# HDMI input raspberry

Tags: hdmi

I would like to know if it is possible to process images that come from an HDMI source (not a camera) with a Raspberry Pi and openCV. Even by using the hdmi to csi-2 bridge (b102), or by using hdmi to usb? Knowing that the HDMI source is NOT encrypted.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible to use the HDMI port on the RPi as a video capture device. The HDMI port on the RPi is an output only port. It can receive some basic status messages ([HDMI-CEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#CEC)), but it isn't able to receive video in.

You can buy [hardware](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00PC5HUA6) that is designed to operate as a video capture device, but in general, it's pretty pricy.